# How to hit the server that spawned me from a silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, webclient

This is probably a noob question, but I can't seem to find the answer.  I am building a Silverlight 3 app that's in the browser.  I want to hit a web URL on the box where the application came from.

So my question is

1. How do I get the name of the URL where the app came from?
2. What is the proper way to hit the URL?  I've seen WebClient and HttpWebRequest and all that.  What is the accepted way in the Silverlight community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri`
2. Both classes are valid; I personally prefer `WebClient`